# When should I call cmd.Process.Release() explicitly?

Tags: go

I could not know when the command will return the result, and a default timer is set. Then I have this question.

```golang
sigChan := make(os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(sigChan, SIGCHLD)
cmd := exec.Command(...)
cmd.Start()
select {
    case <-time.After(1e9):
    // kill the process and release?
    case <-sigChan:
    // the process has been terminated
}
```

Comment: forgot to add syscall package to SIGCHLD, please don't mind it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `exec.CommandContext()` if you want to terminate the command after a timeout.

Then, you need to wait until the command returns to get its result. So, use `cmd.Run()` instead of `cmd.Start()`. If blocking is a concern, then spawn a goroutine that blocks and waits for the command to terminate.

For instance:

```
go func() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 100*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, ...)
    err := cmd.Run()
    //Process error or results
}()
```